# Is the intersection of $\left[a,a+\frac1n\right), n=1,2,3,\cdots$ an empty set?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Is the intersection of $\left[a,a+\dfrac1n\right), n=1,2,3,\cdots$ an empty set? And is the intersection of $[-\infty,-n), n=1,2,3,\cdots$ an empty set in the extended real number set $\mathbb R^*$?

It seems that all the sets such as $\left[a,a+\dfrac1n\right)$ include $a$, but when take a limit of $n$, it looks like $[a,a)$. And there is no nested intervals theorem for such an interval. Does that mean our intuition is actually false? How about $[-\infty,-n)$ in $\mathbb R^*$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $a$ belongs to every set $\left[a,a+\frac1n\right)$, it belongs to $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[a,a+\frac1n\right)$. Actually, $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\left[a,a+\frac1n\right)=\{a\}$.

And, in the extended real line, $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}[-\infty,n)=\{-\infty\}$.

Comment: But why we don't have a theorem of nested intervals for half–closed intervals since a belongs to [a,a+1/n) for every n?

Comment: Because, for instance,$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\left(a,a+\frac1n\right]=\emptyset.$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if $x$ is a real number,
$$x \in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} \big[ a,a+\tfrac{1}{n} \big)$$
if and only if $a\leq x<a+\tfrac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, that is, $0\leq x-a<\frac{1}{n}$ **for all** $n\in\mathbb N$. Of course, this implies that $x-a=0$ and then
$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} \big[ a,a+\tfrac{1}{n} \big) = \{a\}.$$

Comment: Are you sure that inequition also establishes even n→+∞? It will be like a<a

Comment: No, think about this: we have $x-a\geq0$, that is, $x-a=0$ or $x-a>0$. Suppose that $x-a>0$. By the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields) of $\mathbb R$, there is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\tfrac{1}{N}<x-a$, but this is a contradiction, since $x-a<\tfrac{1}{n}$ for *any* $n\in\mathbb N$.